# How to record a full screen with only internal audio on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, screen-recorder

I have an HP Spectre laptop with Windows 10 OS. I tried to record a video (a lecture) with the screen recorder Windows 10 offers (win+alt+R), but then I faced 2 problems:

1. When it records, I don't know how to turn off my microphone without turing off the sound from the video. I only want to hear to internal audio (the audio from the video) without hearing myself.
2. I can't record on full screen (when I press the full screen button or F11 it stops the recording automatically).
   *Note- I have premission to record that lecture for self use so there is no copy rights violations. I only need it because I can't always watch it online.

Is there any solution to it without installing a special program? If not, what good program could I use for that? Quicktime?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it possible to simply [disable the microphone](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-microphone-windows-10/) before recording? Also, you may wish to clarify what you mean by "I can't record on full screen." I am guessing this is for a video game?

Comment: @Anaksunaman  no it is for a lecture, I'll clarify that. Thanks for the guide, I will try that. However, when I did try to disable the microphone in another way I wnded up disabling the sound from the lecture as well.

Comment: You may need to enable the "Stereo Mix" audio input. To do this, open the Sound Control Panel and right-click on the "Stereo Mix" device. Select "Enable" from the context menu. Here are the 5 ways https://www.easeus.com/video-editing-tips/record-video-on-pc-in-windows-10.html to assist Windows 10 PC users in recording videos on their computers with a simple click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out- I just needed to open the video on full screen, then press Win + G and start recording :)
If I press on the microphone icon then to mute- it will only mute myself, leaving the audio of the video still playing.

That's how I achieved my desired result

Answer (score 0):

I generally know two ways to record a full screen with internal audio on Windows 10.
Method 1: Record screen with third-party software like RecMaster

How to Screen Record on HP Laptops with RecMaster?
It is no exaggeration to say that RecMaster helps its consumers get the hang of screen recording most quickly.

1. Download RecMaster and set it up.
2. Double-click the icon and run the application
3. Choose a mode before recording
   For your information, Mobile Phone Mode from Custom Area Mode suits Tik Tok or similar users pretty well. If you have any demand on recording smartphone friendly screen video like 16:9 clip, Mobile Phone Mode is what you seek for.
4. Do settings before recording
   It’s essential to do settings before recording. There are two major ways to achieve your tended configuration – through secondary main window or through directly clicking the Settings option. On its main window, you can select your monitor freely (if you have multiple displays), define the video format, recording quality, frame rate and decide whether to show the webcam/system sound/microphone.
5. Start recording
   a. Once the pre-settings are accomplished, Press the red button to start recording.
   b. Wait for the countdown and then capture the desired portion on the screen.
   c. Use annotation to highlight what you are recording.
   Method 2 – Using HPSR to record a full screen with audio on Windows 10
   How to screen record on HP laptops with HPSR?
6. Download and Install ‘HP Screen Recorder’.
7. After installation, click the option Start > All Programs > HP Software > HP Screen Recorder > MSR Recorder to activate the software.
8. Click the Recorder tray icon and gain access to the main menu.
9. Select Quick Record to start recording.
10. Click Stop to get a raw footage. It is up to you whether to save it, discard it, edit it or not.
11. Save the file and export it in appropriate formats. HPSR supports formats including Flash, AVI, WMV(Window Media Video), MS PowerPoint etc.

However, HPSR falls short if any video length stretches more than 15 minutes. Huge files tend to corrupt is the main reason to cite for. Besides, HPSR is designed to deliver feedback of bugs, so it is not equipped with enough features.